# Vuforia Offline Model Target Generator fails silently

Tags: unity-game-engine, offline, vuforia

I tried to use the Offline Model Target Generator. For that, I converted a CAD STEP file into a JSON file with the help of Automapki's AutoConverter, I also tried converting it to a FBX first and then converting it with FileStar. After that, I ran OMTG with

```
OfflineModelTargetGenerator.exe -i "path/to/xyz.json" -o "path/to/folder" -vu "username" -vp "userpwd"
```

The output was:

```
Offline Model Target Generator
Copyright 2023 PTC Inc. All rights reserved.


[OK] Model Target dataset creation STARTED
```

Followed by the termination of the program, without any error. In the output folder, no new file is visible. What am I doing wrong? Is the json file not in the right format? What is the right JSON format for the files to use in the OMTG?

Answer (score 0):

If you think it may be JSON related, try validating that first: https://jsonlint.com/

If that passes lint, the I suggest that you open an issue here: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/

Be sure to include all relevant details as outlined in the README (OMTG version, etc.). If you can also include the input file, that would be helpful as well.